# How to merge the duplicate results in array

Tags: arrays, merge

I have the result of `print_r ($code_16);` like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => admin
            [phone] => 353534545
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => admin
            [phone] => 353534545
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => admin
            [phone] => 353534545
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => admin
            [phone] => 353534545
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => HTC
            [phone] => 5464565
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => HTC
            [phone] => 5464565
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => HTC
            [phone] => 5464565
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => Test 1
            [phone] => 024345346
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => HTC
            [phone] => 5464565
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => HTC
            [phone] => 5464565
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => HTC
            [phone] => 5464565
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 17
            [name] => ABDC
            [phone] => 545656
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => HTC
            [phone] => 5464565
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => HTC
            [phone] => 5464565
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => HTC
            [phone] => 5464565
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => admin
            [phone] => 353534545
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => admin
            [phone] => 353534545
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => admin
            [phone] => 353534545
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => admin
            [phone] => 353534545
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 18
            [name] => ABCDE
            [phone] => 3453463456
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
            [name] => demo
            [phone] => 5675454
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
            [name] => demo
            [phone] => 5675454
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
            [name] => demo
            [phone] => 5675454
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
            [name] => demo
            [phone] => 5675454
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
            [name] => demo
            [phone] => 5675454
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
            [name] => demo
            [phone] => 5675454
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
            [name] => demo
            [phone] => 5675454
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
            [name] => demo
            [phone] => 5675454
            [notes] => 
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
            [name] => demo
            [phone] => 5675454
            [notes] => 
        )

)
```

How can I merge the similar results? Thanks

Comment: yikes, you need to format your post. indent code by 4 spaces

Comment: I dont know what language are you using, but independently from language or platform you can use Set datastructure ( http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28abstract_data_type%29) which guarantee uniqueness of data

Comment: It would be amazing if you would tell us which language you're using here...